# How is the $ inf $ defined in a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, supremum-and-infimum

In my lecture  notes:

**definition:**

In a metric space $(X,d)$ the distance $d(p,E)$ from a point $p \in X$ and a subset $E\subseteq X$ is defined as:  $d(p,E)=inf\{d(p,x)| x \in E\}$

**Proposition:** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $E\subseteq X$,

$p\in Cl(E)$ if and only if $d(p,E)=0$

**proof:**

By definition of $ inf$ there exists a sequence $p_n$ in $E$ such that
$\lim_{n\to\infty} d(p_n,p)=0$.

So $p$ is the limit of a sequence in $E$ iff  $p\in Cl(E)$

**I am having trouble with the first part, how is  the $inf$ in a metric space defined and how is it proved that the definition applied to $d(p,E)$ is equivalent to the existence of that converging sequence?**

I was trying to use this one

$y=inf(X)  $iff $  \forall \varepsilon >0,  \exists x \in X$ such that $y\leq x \leq y+ \varepsilon$
The problem is that it is valid for $\mathbb{R}$, and couldn't generalized to a metric space.

Comment: $d(p,x)\in \mathbb R$

Comment: $\inf$ is not defined in a metric space. It is defined in partially ordered sets.

Comment: @tomasz The real numbers is a metric space, but we have the inf , right? I guess you meant it  is not ALWAYS defined

Comment: No, I meant that the concept of $\inf$ has nothing to do with metric spaces. Similarly, multiplication and addition is also defined in the real numbers, but neither is a metric concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infimum $\inf\{d(p,x):x\in E\}$ is just the ordinary infimum of a set of non-negative real numbers. It doesn’t matter that the real numbers happen to have been obtained as distances in some metric space: this is still just a set of real numbers, and since it’s bounded below (by $0$), it must have an infimum.

If $d(p,E)=0$, i.e., if $\inf\{d(p,x):x\in E\}=0$, then by the definition of infimum for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n\in E$ such that $d(p,x_n)<\frac1n$, which by definition means that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}d(p,x_n)=0$.

**Added:** To prove the proposition, suppose first that $p\in\operatorname{cl}E$. Then for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n\in B_d\left(p,\frac1n\right)\cap E$, where $B_d(y,r)$ is the open ball of $d$-radius $r$ centred at $y$; clearly this means that $d(p,x_n)<\frac1n$.

Let $D=\{d(p,x):x\in E\}$; $d(p,x)\ge 0$ for each $x\in E$, so $0$ is a lower bound for $D$, so $D$ has an infimum, say $\alpha$. By definition $\alpha$ is a lower bound for $D$, and if $\beta$ is any lower bound for $D$, then $\beta\le\alpha$, so $0\le\alpha$. Suppose that $\alpha>0$; then there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<\alpha$. But then $d(p,x_n)<\frac1n<\alpha$, and $\alpha$ isn’t a lower bound for $D$ (since certainly $d(p,x_n)\in D$). Thus, $\inf D=0$.

(Note that the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ does converge to $p$, though we don’t actually need to use this fact explicitly.)

For the other direction, suppose that $p\notin\operatorname{cl}E$. Then there is an $r>0$ such that $B_d(p,r)\cap E=\varnothing$. Thus, $d(p,x)\ge r$ for each $x\in E$, $r$ is a lower bound for $D=\{d(p,x):x\in E\}$, and by definition $\inf D\ge r$ and hence $\inf D>0$.

Comment: I am not sure how you get a sequence out of the definition of inf, and what definition are you using exactly?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: The usual definition. Suppose that for some $n\ge 1$ there were no such point $x_n$: then we’d have $\frac1n\le d(p,x)$ for every $x\in E$, and $0$ wouldn’t be the infimum after all. The infimum would then be at least $\frac1n$.

Comment: why does the inf or better, the d(p,E )have to be $0$? Couldn't it be some  positive number?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: If it were some $r>0$, the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $p$ would be disjoint from $E$, so $p$ wouldn’t be in the closure of $E$. Do you want me to expand the proof of the proposition?

Comment: Yes, please, I am still not getting the inf definition and how to get the sequence out of it, Could you give more details and also write the definition of Inf to see step by step how to go from it to the thesis

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{d(p,x)\mid x\in E\}$ is a set of non-negative real numbers. So, $\inf\{d(p,x)\mid x\in E\}$ is simply the infimum of a subset of $\Bbb R$.